# Finding the largest values in SAS (Top 3)

Tags: sas

i am new in SAS and I have a little problem. I try to choose 3. largest value from substring in names of files in directory. why i can't do that?

```
parent=directory

data files_and_folders;
 keep num;
    did=dopen("parent");
    if dnum(did)>3 then do;
        do i=1 to dnum(did);
        names=int(substr(dread(did,i),9,8));
        num=largest(3,names);
        output;
end;
end;
output;
run;

returns
names:
20160322
20160323
20160324
20160325
20160325

but returns null value for num
thanks for help
```

Comment: There's a very similar question here. https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Top-and-bottom-2-by-city-using-a-data-step/m-p/262035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `names` is a single number.
`largest` gives you the largest value in a list of values.
e.g.

```
k=1
n=largest(k, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

result: n = 4

```
 k=2
 n=largest(k, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

result: n = 3

You are trying to get the third largest value out of a list of one. That results in a missing.

You need to output the whole file. Sort it `by descending names`. Then limit it to the first three observations e.g. by obs=3 in a set statement